# igb_uio kernel module is not getting inserted?

Tags: kernel

I am using `dpdk` for network interfaces and want to bind interface with `igb_uio` module.
But, while adding `igb_uio` module into kernel using

```
sudo modprobe igb_uio
```

I am getting an error as follows:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module igb_uio not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an out of tree module so it is not available in general.

But in Ubuntu 17.04 and later there is the package [dpdk-igb-uio-dkms](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dpdk-igb-uio-dkms) which will make that available.

Before that you could only use some cards with the generic uio-pci-generic module which is in kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this first:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dpdk-igb-uio-dkms
```